# required class inside namespace cannot instantiate

Tags: php, class, namespaces, include, loader

Ok, i made 3 files i have `index.php` where i include the `namespace.php` where i have 2 functions:

```
Namespace namespaceName{

class classLoader{
         public function __construct() {
            //not used
         }

         public function executeFunctionOutsideTheNamespace() {
            include("class.php");
             new classExtended("badass");
        }
}

class classBase{
    public function __construct(){

    }
}
}
```

Now from `index.php` i try dynamically to call a function from a third file `class.php` where is a class that extends one class from `namespaces`. Here is the `class.php` code

```
class classExtended extends namespaceName\classBase
{    
    public function __construct($action) {
        echo $action;
    }
}
```

And of course my `index.php` file

```
require("namespace.php");

$namespace= new namespaceName\classLoader(); 
$oController = $namespace->executeFunctionOutsideTheNamespace();
```

`$oController` is instance of `classLoader()` right? now i call the function `executeFunctionOutsideTheNamespace` from  class `classLoader()` from namespace `namespaceName` and i tell to `include("class.php");` and to instantiate extended class witch is a estension of classBase fromNamespace. I recide a `Fatal error: Class 'namespaceName\classExtended' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\exercices\namespace.php on line 10`

Comment: Right - the file `class.php` doesn't declare a namespace, and so is at the global namespace. It doesn't inherit the namespace of the file that included it, so you would need to use `new \classExtended()`.  Is that your question?

Comment: yes i thing the class is in the `globalNamespace\classExtended()` and my namespace is `namespaceName` so are 2 namespaces i want the class that extends the `namespaceName\classBase` also be in `namespaceName` not outside in `globalNamespace` my question is then how i include the extended class in `namespaceName` ?

Comment: You need to place it in `namespaceName` with a declaration at the top of its file `namespace namespaceName;`  I'll write this up as an answer below.

Comment: ok, i need to extend global namespace like this `class classExtended extends \namespaceName\classBase`

Comment: Or just leave the namespace out when extending, as I did below. Since they're already in the same namespace you don't need to prefix it.

Comment: yess, so now if i leave the namespace out i will ned to call the function like this: `new classExtended("badass");` . So are you telling me that is a possibility not use `include("class.php");` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67764/discussion-between-johni-devo-and-michael-berkowski).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that `class.php` was `include()`ed inside of the `classLoader` class, which resides inside the `namespaceName` namespace *does not cause it to inherit the namespace* from the including file.

So including `class.php` loads the class `classExtended` into the global namespace, meaning to access it as your code is, you would need to use

```
new \classExtended("cool");
```

In order to get `classExtended` into the namespace `namespaceName`, since it resides in its own file you will need to declare the namespace in that file.  Doing this also means you need to remove `namespaceName` from the  `extends` declaration, lest PHP start looking for the nested `namespaceName\namespaceName\classBase`.  The file `class.php` must become

```
namespace namespaceName;

// Declare the class without the namespace in extends
// since classExtended is now in the same namespace as classBase
class classExtended extends classBase
{    
    public function __construct($action) {
        echo $action;
    }
}
```

I would strongly recommend becoming familiar with the [PSR-4 class autoloading standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) defined by the PHP Framework Interoperability Group, and use [Composer](http://getcomposer.org) to handle your class autoloading. Namespacing then becomes mostly a matter of filesystem layouts, and file inclusion is handled automatically.